# Graceful 'Access denied' message when SSH to a server protected with SSSD fails

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, authentication, sssd

I'm using SSSD on Ubuntu for authn/authz. This works great, but I am getting a "Server unexpectedly closed network connection" when I try to SSH to the box with an unauthorized user.

I can log in successfully with an authorized user, and I can get an "Access Denied" message when I mistype my password with an authorized user. If I attempt to log in with an unauthorized user, then I don't get that pretty "Access Denied" message.

Is there something in the pam module or some other config that is triggering an error and not allowing for a graceful denial message?

I appreciate your help in advance! Thank you!